# Understanding an application of Riemann-Roch in an article

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I saw the following in an article:

Let $C$ be an irreducible smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $K$ and let $g$ be its genus.
By Riemann-Roch, if N is large enough for every line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ of degree $\leq g+1$, $\mathcal{O}(N)|_C\otimes\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ is generated by its global sections. It follows that, for $N$ large enough any function on $C$ with at most $g+1$ poles is the quotient of two homogeneous polynomials of degree $N$.

Why is this true? What is the connection two the fact that it is generated by global sections?

(crossposted from: [Understanding an application...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818168/understanding-an-application-of-riemann-roch-in-an-article))

Comment: It follows from RR that a line bundle on a smooth projective curve is ample if and only if its degree is positive. This implies what you need. If you want a proof of this fact, it is somewhere in Section 3 of Chapter IV in [Hartshorne77].

Comment: Actually, I've just realized that if your $\mathscr O(1)$ means an ample line bundle, then the statement is a consequence of the definition of *ample*. If it only means a line bundle of positive degree, then you need the above. :)

Comment: I think the OP's concerns begin with "it follows that..."

Comment: @Hoot1-you're right. They want to show that every function on the curve is a product of quotients of hom. polynomials a of degree N. They first show that every function is a product of functions with at most g+1 poles (Riemann-Roch and induction). The next part, which I've quotes is what I don't understand.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry I misunderstood the issue. In my defense, the title says "understanding an application of RR" and you don't need RR for that part. Let me add an answer for that then.

Answer (score 3):

The poles of your function determine an effective divisor of degree at most $g+1$ which in turn determines a line bundle $\mathscr L$ of degree at most $g+1$ and with an appropriate embedding of $\mathscr L$ into $\mathscr K_C$, the constant sheaf determined by $K(C)$ the original function corresponds to a global section of this $\mathscr L$.

The statement you would like follows if you can embed $\mathscr L$ into $\mathscr O(N)|_C$, since the global sections of the latter correspond to quotients of homogenous polynomials of degree $N$. (Here I am assuming that $C$ is embedded into a projective space $\mathbb P^n$ and $\mathscr O(1)=\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$, which you never said, but you should have!). Well, actually you need a little more, because you want to do this as subsheaves of $\mathscr K_C$.

An embedding of of $\mathscr L$ into $\mathscr O(N)|_C$ is the same as a global section of $\mathscr O(N)|_C\otimes \mathscr L^{-1}$. In other words, every global section of $\mathscr O(N)|_C\otimes \mathscr L^{-1}$ gives you an embedding of of $\mathscr L$ into $\mathscr O(N)|_C$. You need global generation to guarantee that you can do this inside $\mathscr K_C$.

Comment: Yes I should have! Aren't the global sections of O(n) polynomials? Can you elaborate more on the last paragraph? Why does this give an embedding?

Comment: The global sections of $\mathscr O(N)$ *correspond* to polynomials. Polynomials don't give you functions on the projective space. The way this correspondence works is that you have to pick one degree $N$ polynomial, say $x_0^N$ and use its inverse to identify $\mathscr O(N)$ with a subsheaf of $\mathscr K$. Then every hom poly of degree $N$ gives you a section. If you choose a different embedding, you get a different correspondence. This is the idea behind everything in the last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand that it gives an embedding, it follows since $\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{-1}$ is isomorphic to the structure sheaf and $\mathcal{O}(N)|_C$ is an $\mathcal{O}_C$-module. I still don't understand where I'm using global generation. I take $\mathcal{L}$ embedded in $\mathscr{K}_C$ and so is $\mathcal{O}(N)|_C$.

Comment: And another - does it mean that given a point $a$ on the curve I can always write $f$ as a quotient of hom. pol where the denominator does not vanish on $a$?